# Guessing a string , character by character

Tags: java, string, words

I have an assignment that I'm struggling with and I was wondering if someone could help me. 
I am supposed to create a program that guesses the correct letters in a string of characters. I have a string called alphabet which has all the letters of the alphabet in it and a string that is entered by the user. as the user guesses the correct letters the letters would show up and the unguessed letters remain as a question mark in the string like this. say for example the string is I like popcorn, and the user guessed `p` it should look like this: `? ???? p?p????.` and say they guess another correct letter like i, it would change to : `i ?i?? p?p????.` here is my code i don't know where to go from here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Characters {
    // This class controls a while loop
    // use at least 7 methods
    public static void charactersMethod() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner scan = new  Scanner(System.in);
        String choice;
        Introduction();
        readString();
        guessChar();
        do {
            Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Would you like to play this game again? (Yes/No)");
            choice = Scan.next();
        }
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }

    private static void Introduction() throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to characters game!");
        System.out.println("This game prompts for a string of words. it then allows the player to guess the characters in the string.");
        System.out.println("it then keeps track of all of the characters guessed and tells the player he wins when");
        System.out.println("he guesses all the correct characters in the string.");

    }

    public static void readString() throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString;
        String guessedString;
        System.out.println("Please enter a string");

        originalString = Keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("original string: " + originalString);
        System.out.println("guessed string: ?????????");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Characters to choose from: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.");
        // when a correct letter is guessed, originalString - guess;
    }
    public static void guessChar()  throws InterruptedException
    {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        String guess;   
        System.out.println("Please guess a character: ");
        guess = Scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Character read: " + guess);
        while (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {

            System.out.println("The new String is " + originalString);
    }
    }
    public static void getRidChar() throws InterruptedException {

        }
        private static void sleepDemonstration() throws InterruptedException
        {

        }


    }
```

Comment: How i miss the time i could write really fun programs! :-)

Comment: Your guessChar functionality is a bit off. You are reading in a line, not a character, and then saying while that string equals (regardless of case) "a" print out that string. That isn't really what you want to do. How I wish I had 20 minutes to sit down and write this for you :P

Comment: instead of doing while(guess.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) do guessString = originalString; then for(int i = 0; i < guessString.length; i++){ if (guessString.charAt(i) == guess){ guessString.replace(guess,"");}} if(guessString.equals("")){ //YOU GUESSED THE STRING } Just as a start

Answer (score 0):

You could create two Char arrays one being the string to guess and one being the characters plus ? that have been guessed.

```
//Create char array out of String
char[] originalCharArray = originalString.toCharArray();

//Pass the two char arrays plus the guess to checkGuess

public char[] checkGuess (char[] originalCharArray, char[] guessedCharArray, Char guess) {
   for (int i = 0; i < originalCharArray.length; i++) {
       if (orignalCharArray[i] == guess) {
          guessedStringArray[i] = guess;
       }
   }
}

//This method initializes the guess array to '?'

public char[] init(char[] guessedStringArray) {
    for(int i = 0; i < guessedStringArray.length; i++) {
       guessedStringArray[i] = '?';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i am fairly new at java , could you maybe explain a little further? it would be greatly appreciated. and what do you mean pass it to the first method? do you mean place the code inside my first method?

Comment: also we haven't learned arrays and chars yet, well mostly arrays. i don't know how to initialize arrays and chars...

Comment: @user3386399 Well a String is just an array of chars, so I guess you have been using them. First method as in the first method below that sentence, I will clarify. This is pretty low level manipulation. The other way you could do it would be with `.indexOf` in the String library